# Centering content in an element, and also locking a navbar to the bottom (Use a flexbox?How?)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to set up a landing welcome page that will fill the entire viewport of the users browser.Id like to have some centered content above it, maybe some text or a slideshow of some sort. I've centered content before, that's not the real issue here. I also need to pin a navbar to the bottom of the element. I cant use absolute positioning because i need it to stick to the top of the window when i scroll past it. I've tried doing this with a flexbox, but have run into a large number of issues. First is that the navbar is starting from the middle and second is that centered content is not quite in the middle, it appears to be slightly to the right of the center.

Here's the css i'm using:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}

.full-size {
    height: 100vh;
}

#page-welcome {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/1920/1080);
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.align {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    height:100%;
}
.align > .end{
    align-self:flex-end;
}
.align > .top{
    align-self:flex-start;
}
```

I also have a CodePen that demonstrates my problems here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GCpzE

Comment: Not every browser understands the vh/vw units, particularly mobile browsers.  It's best if you provide a fallback of some sort or everything is going to end up squished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the direction is set to *row*, but what you need is *column*.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/bCDfL

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.full-size {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#page-welcome {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/1920/1080);
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.align {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I've added an extra element to the demo so that you can see that it will be vertically centered (though how close to perfectly centered it is will depend on how tall the other elements are).

Comment: Thanks for the help, you've solved my problem with the navbar, but now im not to vertically center the foo div without the h1 above it. I may be missing something, im pretty new to using css for this type of thing, usually just use js.

Comment: This is about all you can really do with Flexbox.  You can't just have an item in the middle and an item at the bottom, unless the item at the bottom is absolutely positioned or you use a nested flex container for your middle item or you have an invisible element at the top.